# remove status bar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Trying to hide the status bar in iOS SwiftUI on the first view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
           
        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewC()) {
                    Text("New View")
                }  
            }.offset(y: 100)
            
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .accentColor(.white)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
}
```

The status bar is still showing on the initial view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a SwiftUI bug. The possible valid workaround is to use UIKit view controller, as representable, to manage status bar hidden.

Here is a demo of possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

```
class StatusBarHideHelper: UIViewController {
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { true }    // << important !!
}

struct StatusBarHideHelperView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        StatusBarHideHelper()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

and now we can use it in our SwiftUI view hierarchy, like

```
var body: some View {
       
    NavigationView {
        VStack {

            NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewC()) {
                Text("New View")
            }  
        }.offset(y: 100)
        
    }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    .background(StatusBarHideHelperView())                // << this !!
    .accentColor(.white)
```

Comment: This worked for me if I also added `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in the helper viewController's viewWillAppear, and set `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` to true for the `UIHostingController` that was presenting my SwiftUI view.

Answer (score 0):

**Try that one**

```
struct ContentView: View {

 @State var hideStatusBar = false

var body: some View {
    Button("Toggle Status Bar") {
        withAnimation {
            self.hideStatusBar.toggle()
        }
    }
    .statusBar(hidden: hideStatusBar)
}
}
```